# Weird MetaPost output when using PNG

Tags: eps, metapost, png

Whenever I try to output PNGs with metapost, I get really bizarre outputs. For reference, I'm using Windows 7 with MiKTeX 2.9.

The metapost code I'm using is adapted from the metafont example on the latter's wikipedia page:

```
outputformat := "png";
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.%o";

beginfig(1);
    h=100;
    w=100;
    y1=y2=y3=0;
    y4=y5=y6=h;
    x1=x4=0;
    x2=x5=w;
    x3=x6=2*w;
    pickup pencircle xscaled 0.2w yscaled 0.04w rotated 45;
    draw z1..z3..z6{z2-z6}..z5..{z4-z2}z4..cycle;
endfig;
end.
```

When I generate eps files, the output works fine (the code is the same as above, save for substituting 'eps' for 'png'). Here is a screenshot of the eps output:

[image]

However, when I try to generate a PNG, this is what I get:

[image]

I have no clue what's going on, and I haven't been able to find any reference to this specific problem.

Comment: It seems to be the combination of `pencircle` and `rotate 45`. With `pensquare` all is well or you can fiddle with the rotation. (Actually, this gives an inkling what's happening I think - try varying the angle.)

Comment: Thank you for the report. I have added an issue at
http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=976

Comment: @LuigiScarso oh, thanks! I guess I just assumed I was doing something wrong, but this does appear to be some sort of bug.

Comment: As a workaround, you could use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to convert .eps to .png.  This works very reliably with MP output.

Comment: @Thruston yeah, what I ended up doing is just writing a script to convert the EPS output to PNG with ghostscript

Comment: You can do an approximated pencircle in this way:

pen penpseudocircle;
path p[];
numeric L,S;
L=360;
S:=0.5;
p1000 :=  S*(cosd(0),sind(0))  for i=1 upto L-1: -- S*(cosd(i/L*360.0), sind(i/L*360.0)) endfor -- cycle;
penpseudocircle  = makepen( p1000 );

and the use it instead of a true pencircle:

%% correct  in png and eps format
pickup penpseudocircle xscaled 0.2w yscaled 0.04w rotated 45;
draw z1..z3..z6{z2-z6}..z5..{z4-z2}z4..cycle withcolor red;

Comment: It should be fixed in rev. 2102 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like this is a bug in Metapost. The solution I came up with was to simply write a shell script which takes the EPS output and converts it into PNG with ghostscript